# Appengine deployment migrates all traffic to one version

Tags: google-app-engine

I have 2 versions x & y for A/B testing in an appengine module. I want 95%-5% ratio for traffic which I am able to configure from the panel. The problem is - Whenever I make a deployment to the module, appengine automatically routes all traffic to x or y. And its totally random, sometimes 100% of traffic goes to x and sometimes y. It is something that I am missing from docs, or it is supposed to happen this way?

```
mvn gcloud:deploy -Dapp.id=test-project -Dapp.module=alpha -Dapp.version=x
mvn gcloud:deploy -Dapp.id=test-project -Dapp.module=alpha -Dapp.version=y
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use the `--no-promote` flag when deploying your apps:

`mvn gcloud:deploy -Dapp.id=test-project -Dapp.module=alpha -Dapp.version=x --no-promote`
`mvn gcloud:deploy -Dapp.id=test-project -Dapp.module=alpha -Dapp.version=y --no-promote`

For more info, check out this doc: [Testing and Deploying Your Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app).

Comment: No, it doesn't work. We are using java, and its mentioned in php.

Comment: It's unrelated to the application programming language. See [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) documentation. Note that "promote the deployed version to receive all traffic" is True by default. `gcloud` offers the `--no-promote` flag to avoid that behaviour on each deployment. Or you can change the default behaviour to False with this command: `gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false`.